# How to use order_by with first()?

Tags: r, dplyr

When I run a simple version of `first(...)` with `order_by`, my R crashes.  For example the following

```
library(dplyr)
summarize(group_by(mtcars, cyl), bigmpg = last(mpg, order_by = wt))
```

crashes my R.

Is this a bug (perhaps related to [`dplyr` issue #626](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/626)) or is something else wrong?

I'm running R version 3.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64) and dplyr version 0.5.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Works fine for me, though if you're going to use dplyr, you should _really_ use pipes; that's utterly unreadable.

Comment: @alistaire Interesting.  Which versions of R and dyplyr are you running?  (Incidentally, I agree with you about pipes.  I copied the snippet from dplyr issue as-is.)

Comment: The same. On OS X, if it matters.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks.  Should have mentioned I'm on Windows.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: It sounds like a bug if it's reproducible; I'd file a report on GitHub if there isn't a similar open one.

Comment: @alistaire It turns out there may, in fact, be a similar bug (https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2081); the example in the bug crashes on my machine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try qualifying the dplyr functions.

```
library(magrittr)
requireNamespace("dplyr")

dplyr::data_frame(id = 1:9, value = 42) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    dplyr::first(value, order_by = id)
  )
```

This work-around avoids the crash for me.  Your example crashed on my Red Hat 6.7, Ubuntu 14.04, Windows 7, & Windows 8 machines (R 3.3.1; dplyr 0.5.0).

Comment: This works for me too.  I can shorten it to `library(dplyr)` followed by `data_frame(id = 1:9, value = 42) %>% summarise(dplyr::first(value, order_by = id))` (so it seems only `first(...)` needs qualification).  Thanks!

Comment: I'll accept this (since it actually solves the problem!) although I thank that technically the answer to my question is that it's a bug.